# Android Floating Action Button failing on real devices but not in emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

I'm facing a weird issue than I don't know how to solve: I have ready a layout with a Floating Action Button (fab). In emulator it works perfectly, but when executing my app in real devices it thorws a runtime exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{soyacm.es.com.bookgame/soyacm.es.com.bookgame.ui.bookDetail.BookDetailActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #183: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3150)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1734)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
                                                                         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #183: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
```

Exception leads me directly to the setContentView(R.layout.activity_book_detail); line

Emulator runs with Android API24, and devices runs with API 22 and API 23 (both failing).

Here is the libs I'm importing on my gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

My layout is the following (reduced):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
       ...
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/read_book_action"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/read_book_icon"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/not_so_white_background"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Does anybody figure out where the error could be?

Comment: what is your compiled SDK version ?

Comment: Use app:backgroundTint="@color/your_color" instead of android:backgroundTint.

Comment: try it and let me know please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try editing this line.. `android:backgroundTint="@color/not_so_white_background"`

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/read_book_action"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/read_book_icon"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/not_so_white_background"
    android:elevation="6dp"
 />
```

To

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/read_book_action"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/read_book_icon"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/not_so_white_background"
    android:elevation="6dp"
/>
```

Comment: Working!! That was the problem. Thanks a lot! Just for knowing it for future: when to use android: or app: which is the logic behind of this?